# To find hottest point on probe surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, proof-writing, maxima-minima

A space probe in form of ellipsoid $4x^2+y^2+4z^2=16$ enters earth atmosphere and its surface begins to heat. After one hour, temperature at point $(x,y,z)$ on probe surface is given by $$T(x,y,z) = 8x^2+4yz-16z+1600.$$ Find hottest point on the surface probe.

I computed gradient of $T$ but don't know how to proceed next.
Thanks for help.

Comment: This looks a lot like an exercise in using the Lagrange multiplier method. Have you studied that?

Comment: i know the method but don't see how it can be applied here?

Comment: You have an objective function $T$ and the constraint given by the equation of the ellipsoid.

Comment: ok I will try that

Comment: The Lagrange multiplier computations are rather tedious, but straightforward. The answer you accepted below is much less work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T(x,y,z)\leq8x^2+2(y^2+z^2)-16z+1600=$$
$$=8x^2+2y^2+8z^2-6z^2-16z+1600=$$
$$=-6z^2-16z+1632=-\frac{2}{3}(3z+4)^2+\frac{4928}{3}\leq\frac{4928}{3}.$$
The equality occurs for $(x,y,z)=\left(\pm\frac{4}{3},-\frac{4}{3},-\frac{4}{3}\right)$ only, which says that we got a maximal value and two needed points.

Comment: can you elaborate. I cannot understand anything

Comment: @J. Deff Yes, of course! What exactly?

Comment: literally everything. which method is this ?

Comment: @J. Deff It's a solution of your problem. Is the first step clear?

Comment: no its not clear

Comment: @J. Deff I It's $4yz\leq2y^2+2z^2,$ which is $(y-z)^2\geq0,$ which is obvious.

Comment: why have you started with <

Comment: @J. Deff Because we look for the maximum occurring.

Comment: how have you found x and y

Comment: @J. Deff The equality occurs for $4yz=2y^2+2z^2,$ which gives $y=z$ and from the last step for $z=-\frac{4}{3}.$ Now, we can substitute $y=z=-\frac{4}{3}$ in the condition, which gives $x=\frac{4}{3}$ or $x=-\frac{4}{3}.$

Comment: I understand now but this method is non intuitive to me , like what you did in 4yz < 2y^2 + 2z^2

Comment: @J. Deff $2y^2+2z^2-4yz=2(y^2+z^2-2yz)=2(y-z)^2\geq0.$ Is it clear?

Comment: yes its clear. but bit tricky and clever

Comment: How did u find values of x and y from value of z ?

Comment: @J. Deff The equality in the first step occurs for $y=z$.